# Stage blink on load

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I need to maximize Stage on load via code.

Here is my code:

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Контрола трошкова кућног буџета");
        primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

I have all needed imports. Problem is when run it primaryStage blink for a part of second in size created in Scene Builder, then maximize as intended and I want it to show Maximized. It happend in Eclipse and when make runnable JAR and run it with *.bat file.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

For testing I created small app in WPF it works properly, no blinking.

EDIT: When stage is in normal size and I click Maximize button, it maximizes stage as I want. Is there possibility to write code to simulate or call Maximize button on top of window? Othere way besides

```
 stage.setMaximized(true);
```

because that line doesn't work well.

Comment: If you try to run it without the style sheet, does it make any difference?

Comment: Just noticed in WPF it animate (fast) from designed size to maximized, it look nice. Any way to do it in JavaFX would be good enough for me.

Comment: @Boris Commented out stylesheet, still same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround, set the stage's opacity to 0 before showing it so the resizing happens while the stage is not visible, then change it back to 1:

```java
primaryStage.setOpacity(0);
primaryStage.show();
primaryStage.setOpacity(1);
```